# Why does using mongoose callback result in saving data twice?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have been wondering why adding a callback to the mongoose findOneAndUpdate function results in saving the data twice to the DB?

```
public async addPersonAsFavorite(userId: string, friendId: string) {
    if (!await this.isPersonAlreadyFriend(userId, friendId)) {
      const friendList = FriendsList.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: userId },
        { $push: { friendsList: friendId } },
        { upsert: true, new: true },
        (err, data) => {
         if (err) console.error(err);
         return data;
        }
      );
      return friendList;
    }}

  public async isPersonAlreadyFriend(userId: string, friendId: string) {
    let isFriendFound = false;
    await FriendsList.findById(userId, (err, data) => {
      if (data) {
        console.log(data.friendsList);
      }
      if (err) console.error(err);
      if (data && data.friendsList.indexOf(friendId) > -1) {
        isFriendFound = true;
        console.log('already friend');
      } else {
        console.log('not friend');
        isFriendFound = false;
      }
    })
    return isFriendFound;
  }
```

If i remove the callback, the data only gets saved once.

EDIT: added second piece of code and new question.
If someone spams the button to add friend. The friend will be added multiple times because before the first friend is added and the check can be done to prevent this it has already added the person multiple times.

How can i make sure that it completes the write to the DB before allowing the function to be called again?

Comment: Why do you have a callback there.. ? Just add await..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the problem is in isPersonAlreadyFriend method, because you are trying to call it using async await but then you are passing a callback, what makes the method not return a promise. The rigth way to use promises with mongodb should be something like this:

```
public async isPersonAlreadyFriend(userId: string, friendId: string) {
    let isFriendFound = false;
    const data = await FriendsList.findById(userId);
    if (data) {
      console.log(data.friendsList);
    }
    if (data && data.friendsList.indexOf(friendId) > -1) {
      isFriendFound = true;
      console.log('already friend');
    } else {
      console.log('not friend');
      isFriendFound = false;
    }
    return isFriendFound;
  }
```

Try with this and let me know if it helps

Comment: Ah i see. the promise needs to resolve to the variable before doing the check and then it will return the promise. Extra question. How can i prevent a function like this being spammed? if someone calls the function multiple times per second they will all be added as a friends before the update function is complete and returns true?

Comment: That's it, other case you are always returning false in your variable.

Comment: The only thing i have been able to find regarding preventing the spamming of a such a function is a frontend disabling of the button or a lock on the function. Are these the best ways of preventing such a problem?

Comment: Maybe you can change findById by a simple find and simplify a little bit the code: 
const data = await FriendsList.findById({userId, friendsList: friendId});
This should return the user only in case it exists and has the friend.

And probably you can use something similar in the update, checking at the same time that the userId is that and it doesn't have the friend yet. Something like this:

FriendsList.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: userId, $not: {friendsList: friendId} },

Check if something like that can works ;)

Comment: Thank yo for the answer. I will look into it. In the meantime i have just put a lock on the function based on the Id.